# Basic Input from html into mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I was trying to use basic php to insert data into a mysql table from an html form. i was succesfull initially with basic plain text inputs. However when i  was trying to input an email id i keep getting this error :

`Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com,moohawks )' at line 3`

My php code is as follows:

```
$firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
    $emailid = $_REQUEST['emailid'];
    $team_name = $_REQUEST['team_name'];
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'incredible';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO users 
       (firstname,lastname,emailid,teamname)
       VALUES ( $firstname,$lastname,$emailid,$team_name )";

mysql_select_db('adb project');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$message2 =  "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

What is wrong with my insert statement. As far I can understand, it looks corrects and fairly simple. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your SQL statement as follows with a single quote for every variable

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users 
       (firstname,lastname,emailid,teamname)
       VALUES ( '$firstname','$lastname','$emailid','$team_name' )";
```